# flask-admin: Cancel update to the Model on particular condition

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm using flask-admin's ModelView class along with an SQLalchemy. I want to check for a particular condition inside the on_model_change() function and cancel the update to the Model if the condition is met.  How do I do it?

I'm able to get rid of the change when a new model is created by doing this (though not my favourite routine):

```
if is_created is True:
    if model.some_condition is True:
        self.delete_model(model)
```

However, I don't see a way of cancelling update when an existing entry is changed.

I also checked `return False`. That didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `on_model_change` and throw exception from there. If app is ran in debug mode, it will show werkzeug debugger and if app is running in release mode, it'll show exception text in a tooltip.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I found your reply at  [https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/issues/173](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/issues/173) quite informative too.